# Opencv binding ios

Tags: c#, ios, opencv, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

I'm trying to create C# **bindings using objective sharpie** for the objective c library of OpenCV 3.4 (https://opencv.org/releases.html, precompiled and build from source with extra modules) **but without success.** Either I'm using the wrong sharpie parameters or something is wrong with the compiled opencv2.framework.

Tools/Versions:

- Sharpie 3.4.0
- Iphone11.2 SDK
- OpenCV 3.4.0 (precompiled and/or successfully build from source with extra modules)

I tried the following sharpie parameters (when current dir contains opencv2.framework):

```
$ sharpie bind -framework opencv2
$ Done. Exiting with error code 1.
error: opencv2: Umbrella header file does not exist: opencv2.framework/Headers/opencv2.h
$
```

That is because the umbrella file is Headers/opencv.hpp. So i changed the parameters to:

```
$ sharpie bind -fx-umbrella opencv2.framework/Headers/opencv.hpp -framework opencv2    
Done. Exiting with error code 1.
error: opencv2: Umbrella header file does not exist: opencv2.framework/Headers/opencv2.h
$
```

which completely gets ignored in every order.

I also tried many other possibilities like defining only the .a file (in combination with removing included libs with lipo):

```
$ sharpie bind opencv2.a
Parsing 1 header files...
warning: [SomePath]/opencv2.a: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-c' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fno-spell-checking' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
warning: argument unused during compilation: '-Xclang -detailed-preprocessing-record' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''
Error while processing [SomePath]/opencv2.a.
Done. Exiting with error code 1.
error: Clang failed to parse input and exited with code 1
$
```

or addressing the umbrella header directly with:

```
$ sharpie bind Headers/opencv.hpp
```

which fails because "opencv2/...hpp" file not found because every included hpp refers to "opencv2/..." structure

Comment: Have you tried to move temporarily the `Headers` folder to `opencv2.framework`?

Comment: I tried but it did not help. In the opencv2.framework directory there is a symbolic link to Versions/A/Headers (Versions/A also contains the .a file) and a symbolic link opencv2 to the .a file (if you have a chance, have a look at the folder structure, link to the package is in my start post)

Answer (score 0):

The fact is quite subtle in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/platform/native-frameworks), however it states that

> The -framework option does not allow explicit header files to be passed.

and also that

> Under the hood, specifying -framework is just a shortcut.

So instead if you need to specify the umbrella header file you can write the parameters as

```
sharpie bind opencv2.framework/Headers/opencv.hpp -scope opencv2.framework/Headers -c -F .
```

This gets the process started but there are a myriad of additional problems ahead. I personally gave up after a day of trying to get sharpie to work with OpenCV, but best of luck to anyone going down that path.